# iperf between 2 interfaces on same host

Tags: linux, networking, routes, iperf

I am looking for a way how I can run iperf benchmark between 2 interfaces on the same host as shown on the schema:

[image: Setup Schema]

Both of the machines (pc and router) are linux.
I'm need a way to run some functional tests on my "router" machine using my only 1 PC with 2 ethernet ports.

I tried already few different ways to solve it but still no luck:

1) Adding static routes for destination hosts with metric

2) Binding iperf to specific ip address

3) Disabling local loopback interface


Basicly what I'm looking for is to run traffic 192.168.1.10<-->1.1.1.10 thru the router device (with ip forwarding enabled).

Comment: Could you add the routing tables on your host computer to your post. Also, consider asking this on http://superuser.com since this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Maybe checkout: https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/865

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to bind the server as well:

For the server run `iperf -s -B 1.1.10` in terminal
and on another terminal instance for the client run `iperf -c 1.1.10 -B 192.168.1.10`
This will normally work if your OS doesn't use the loop-back interface by default.

Comment: No, tried it already, it doesn't work: `[root@localhost ~]# iperf -s -B 1.1.1.10 &
[1] 18312
[root@localhost ~]# ------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
Binding to local address 1.1.1.10
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------

[root@localhost ~]# iperf -c 1.1.1.10 -B 192.168.1.10
connect failed: Connection timed out
[root@localhost ~]#
` Local Loopback (lo) interface is down